# Show that is $F$ is a finite field then, $P_F:=$ the set of all polynomial functions on F is not isomorphic to $F[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that is $F$ is a finite field then, $P_F$ (the set of all polynomial functions on F) is not isomorphic to $F[x]$

It gives the the definition:

an element $\phi \in F^F$ is a polynomial function on $F$, if there exists $f(x) \in F[x]$ such that$\phi(a)=f(a), \forall a \in F$

$F[x]$ is infinite in size.

If I understand the definition above, if F is finite then it has a finite amount of elements. And a $\phi(a)$ exists for all $a \in F$. So if $|F|=k$ then there is $k$ many $\phi$ for each $a \in F$ thus $|P_F|=k^k$, not infinite. therefore the two cannot be isomorphic because they are of different size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is essentially correct, but you have shown that $\left|P_F\right| \leq k^k$, not that $\left|P_F\right| = k^k$. Proving that $\left|P_F\right| = k^k$ is harder (you would need to check that every function $k \to k$ is a polynomial function -- try Lagrange interpolation for this), but unnecessary, since $\leq k^k$ already yields finite.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that.