# If $F$ is a finite field with $|F|=k$, and $P_F$ is the set of polynomial functions from $F$ to $F$, then $|P_F|\leq k^k$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is a link to a previous question, which is relevant to the problem I am asking about (I'm confused about the top answer):

[Show that is $F$ is a finite field then, $P_F:=$ the set of all polynomial functions on F is not isomorphic to $F[x]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1165839/show-that-is-f-is-a-finite-field-then-p-f-the-set-of-all-polynomial-funct)

Can someone explain to me why the number $|P_F|$ is maximized by is $k^k$? Every time I think about it, I keep getting $k^2$. I'm having trouble seeing how to get $k^k$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $P_F$ is a subset of the set of maps of set of $F\rightarrow F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\alpha \in F$. Since the order of the multiplicative group $F^*$ is $k - 1$, we have $\alpha^k = \alpha$. Therefore any polynomial $f(x)$ from $F$ to $F$ can be written with terms of degree at most $k - 1$, i.e.
$$f(x) = a_{k-1}x^{k-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0,$$
where each $a_i \in F$. Now we have $k$ choices for each of the $k$ coefficients, so $\vert P_F \vert \leq k^k$.

Comment: I think this is very nice, but I think the last equality should be inequality $\;\le\;$ since two polynomials can render the same polynomial *function*. +1

Answer (score 0):

If
 for example $\;F=\Bbb F_2\;$ = the field with two elements, then

$$f_1(x)=x(x-1)\,,\,f_2(x)=x^2-x+1\,,\,f_3(x)=x\,,\,f_4(x)=x-1$$

are $\;4=2^2\;$ different polynomial maps.

Try to generalize to $\;p=3,5,\;$ etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\varphi\colon F\to F$ be any function. Suppose $F=\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$, with $|F|=k$. By the general theory of [interpolating polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation), there exists a polynomial $f$ of degree at most $k-1$ such that, for $i=1,2,\dots,k$,
$$
f(a_i)=\varphi(a_i)
$$
Thus every function $F\to F$ is a polynomial function. So the set of polynomial functions has cardinality $k^k$.